# How to process CallBackURL?

Tags: reactjs, response, callbackurl

I am working on the integration of a payment method.
The documentation of the payment method says this:

***If the payment was successful, the third-party system informs our system by means of a call to CallBackURL, previously provided in the redirection request.*** They have explained this by means of a flowchart (Image attached)

I am parsing a CallBackURL in redirection request but I'm not receiving any responses from the third-party system.[image]

Comment: Is the callback URL secure? Most payment gateways don't hit urls which dont have `https`

Comment: @AnshSaini I want to confirm that where should I expect the response. CallBackURL should be a backend or frontend URL

Comment: It should be a backend URL